# Проблемы производительности и Traceview

Tags: android, java

Мне нужно найти причину performance-проблемы в android-приложении. Нашел на официальном сайте [Profiling with Traceview and dmtracedump](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html). Но всё равно абсолютно непонятно, что нужно сделать, чтобы увидеть все эти графики.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой вариант. Пусть есть кнопка, по нажатию на которую, приложение тупит. Подключаем телефон через usb, запускаем ddms, в дереве слева выбираем свой процесс (который уже запущен). Теперь в верхнем ряде кнопок в ddms находим пятую кнопку (три стрелочки налево с красным кружочком). Нажимаем его и делаем на телефоне нужные операции, которые нужно отладить. Потом снова нажимаем в ddms эту же кнопку (красный кружок станет черным квадратом). И ждем несколько секунд (ddms скачает с телефона файлик на несколько мегабайт и запустить traceview. Ну а дальше можно уже смотреть.

Но можно и полупрограммным путем. Находим в коде место, где хочется начать профайлинг. Вставляем туда `Debug.startMethodTracing('имя файла.trace');`. А там, где нужно остановить - `Debug.stopMethodTracing();`. (предупреждение, если остановку не вызвать, то не гарантируется, что файл запишется!). Запускаем, закрываем прогу и идем в '/mnt/sdcard' где берем свой файлик.

А вот как анализировать - это уже отдельная и длинная история.

Comment: Полученный трейс-файл можно открыть в Eclipse и увидеть разную статистику по отдельным методам. Собственно, это и есть то, что нужно.

Comment: Собственно в эклипсе открывает все тот же traceview:) Единственный плюс открытия прямо в эклипсе - возможность сразу перейти на нужную строку в коде.

Comment: Я пишу в Идее, а не в Эклипсе.

Comment: А разве кто то против?:) Сам в Идее пишу.

Comment: @KoVadim, у меня эта кнопка недоступна, хотя процесс Online. Как её сделать доступной?

Comment: в дереве процессов нужно выделить нужный процесс. Иначе как оно узнает, какой процесс исследовать?

Comment: У меня нет никакого дерева. Только список. Прикрепил скрин.

Comment: ну... конечно...
Дерево есть, просто в нем процессов нет:)
В AndroidManifest.xml нужно выставить, что бы процесс был debug="true". А иначе никак.

Comment: Ничего не изменилось. А еще при старте ddms ошибка

>java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine