# Получение результата профилирования android-приложения

Tags: android, java, профилирование

В продолжение темы [Проблемы производительности и Traceview](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/78272/). У меня получилось прикрепиться к процессу, запущенному на телефоне. Оказалось, в Идее надо запускать в режиме выполнения (Run), а не в режиме отладки (Debug). Теперь другая проблема. Я нажимаю "Start Method Profiling", выполняю некоторые действия на девайсе, нажимаю "Stop Method Profiling" (та же кнопка). После этого не происходит ровным счетом ничего. KoVadim писал:

> И ждем несколько секунд (ddms скачает с телефона файлик на несколько мегабайт и запустить traceview).

Какой файлик? Где его искать?
При попытке запустить `traceview` вручную получаю такое сообщение (и больше ничего не происходит):

[image]

То же самое, про установку переменной "Path", пишет и при запуске `ddms`. Хотя я уже установил значение этой переменной. Как же всё-таки получить Profile Panel (дерево с процентами времени, потраченного на каждый метод).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очевидно плохо установили. Вам же чётко инструкция написана: Открываете Мой компьютер-> Свойства-> Дополнительные парметры системы->Дополнительно->Переменные среды    и добавляете путь к java sdk

[image]

Comment: Ну, переменную среды добавлять мне много раз приходилось. Но тут это сообщение не уходит никак. Может, компьютер перезапустить? А у вас этот `traceview` запускается? Кстати, почему ddms пишет то же самое, но при этом работает?